# how to mock the class consists of Static block

Tags: junit

```
static {
    try {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.add("Kiran");
        string s= "Vikram";
        sb.add(s);  }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.fatal("Exception", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest: not at all.

**static** is an abnormality in good OO design. And static init blocks are kinda even worse.

Instead: learn how to write **testable** code, for example by watching those videos over [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). And then change your code to not do such things. And your need to mock those things ... vaporizes.

And especially as the code in your example doesn't have **any** side effect; as none of the variables used in there exist outside of that block. Probably you got some "reduced" example there; and in reality your static block is doing some kind of property init. But even for that case ... you might find better ways to do that; instead of putting them into a static block!